# Removing duplicate data conditionally in Excel

Tags: excel, duplicates, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I'm trying to clean and organize a data set that has user IDs, date and time to the second, and heartrate. What I'm trying to do is change this data set from measuring heartrate by second, to heartrate by minute by removing duplicate values after the first unique value. However, columns A (user IDs) and B (time) are both reliant on each other and both contain duplicates. I need to change it so that there are one unique combination of each for columns A and B together.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYnMh.png)
This is a snapshot of my data.
Example of what I need would be one value for 5/9/2016 19:49 for user ID 123456789, but also one value for 5/9/2016 19:49 for user ID 987654321, and so on for each value of time.

Comment: It is not clear if you want to do this by a formula (then check for `UNIQUE`) keeping the original data. Or if you really want to manipulate the original data - then you would need VBA. Please be more explicit otherwise your question will most likely be closed.

Comment: Would you pls. explain what does it mean `duplicate values before the first unique value`?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It was suppose to say AFTER the first unique value. I've edited my question so it's correct. I do need a formula for this.